# FMRadio Class .NET in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, fm-radio

Is it possible to make FM Radio UWP app. I found only FM Radio Class but it's only for WP7. I know that's maybe question will be abroad but i want to know which classes i should use to make it.

Comment: FMRadio is only supported in Windows Phone 7.1. See the caution block here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769541(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: so that mean that i can't make it

Comment: Not unless you make it for Windows Phone 7

Comment: but who us WP7? :D

Comment: Hey the good news is, they might add it in the future. They seem to have it reserved in their documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioKind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Icemanind's has pointed out, FMRadio API is not supported in UWP by now. At this point, there is only a place holder for FM Radio in the UWP API but unfortunately it is not implemented. You can find the details of this at  [RadioKind enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Radios.RadioKind#fields_).
[image]

If you do want this feature, you are welcome to ask on **UserVoice**. There are already several related suggestions like [Ability to control FM radio via APIs like we did in Silverlight for Windows Phone](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/17399074) and [FM Radio RDS support if FM Radio APIs are brought in](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/17399128). Please feel free to vote on them, your feedback has made Windows better!